# How to display command output in Flask using the Subprocess python module

Tags: python, flask

Below is my code

view.py

```
from flask import render_template
#Import variables stored in _init_.py
from app import app

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
import subprocess
memory = subprocess.Popen(['date'])
out,error = memory.communicate()

return render_template('view.html', out=out, error=error)
```

view.html

{{ out }}

It prints none, none, I am not sure what's wrong as it works fine in the python script

Update : Thanks for the answers, [this](http://techarena51.com/index.php/how-to-install-python-3-and-flask-on-linux/) is how you can do it

Comment: 2 notes - 1. why do use multiple annotations for your REST path 2. please explain "it works fine in my python script", which script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to grab stdout from your command you need to add stdout=subprocess.PIPE as in:

```
memory = subprocess.Popen(['date'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: Is this compulsory? As I was able to display the output of my command without the pipe in my python script, Also, along with the date, I get numbers I am not sure why,

Comment: If you want the output into a variable, yeah. If you don't specify it then it'll go out to the standard out channel, e.g. your command line if you run it as a standalone script.